# JavaFX add objects in TilePane horizontally (TilePane inside a ScrollPane)

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, fxml

I need help inserting objects in a `TilePane` (contained within a `ScrollPane`) horizontally. It inserts horizontally until it reaches the end of the `ScrollPane` then starts adding to the next row of the `ScrollPane`. This is what it looks like:

[image]

The box is the `ScrollPane` and the `TilePane` is what is holding all the images.

Basically, I want the `TilePane` to keep adding to the right and have the `ScrollPane` show a horizontal scrollbar.

Here's my code:

```
private void start()
{
    @FXML private ImageView bigImage;
    @FXML private ScrollPane scrollPane;
    @FXML private TilePane tilePane;

    // Setup scrollpane
    scrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);
    scrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);     
    tilePane.setHgap(15);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(bigImage.getImage());
        imageView.setFitWidth(100);
        imageView.setFitHeight(100);

        tilePane.getChildren().add(imageView);
    }

    //scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);
    scrollPane.setContent(tilePane);
}
```

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="900.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="view.PhotoController">

   <children>       
      <ImageView fx:id="bigImage" fitHeight="441.0" fitWidth="534.0" layoutX="35.0" layoutY="52.0" pickOnBounds="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../../../../../Pictures/Wallpaper02.jpg" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>

      <ScrollPane fx:id="scrollPane" layoutX="35.0" layoutY="528.0" prefHeight="140.0" prefWidth="820.0">
         <content>
            <TilePane fx:id="tilePane" prefHeight="137.0" prefWidth="817.0" />
         </content>
      </ScrollPane>
   </children>

</AnchorPane>
```

How can I accomplish what I want to do? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ccs property "repeat" with your background like this, it will do all the work :

```
-fx-background-image:url("Image.png");
-fx-background-repeat:repeat;
```

For more modification looks in the [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) with the background properties.

Comment: This didn't do anything. The images still get inserted to the next row instead of the to the right.